# Suggestion: Questions with Polls

Tags: feature-request

I usually see many questions asking personal points of view about some subjects on stackoverflow. I already did some, because sometimes is really important see the point of view of others developers, mainly the more experienced ones and also see in which direction the market is going.

However, the most of these questions are closed by the administrators, in some cases I think it's fair enough, but in others we lose precious informations and good discussions. I know there are others Q&A sites more suitable for this.

However, I was wondering about a new kind of category of questions. In several cases the possibility to create polls for some kind of questions would be enough, mainly these ones with personal points of view.

So, What do you think about polls in some questions? Maybe just for some users  with X reputations achieved. Would be useful for Q&A purposes?

Comment: It was argued before. Basic SX idea about Q&A format is "We are looking for answers, not opinions", unless related site is designed for a such purpose from scratch (Area51 proposal). Also, asking question should not have any relation with reputation. Reputation based actions are (nearly) all about moderation.

Answer (score 4):

One of the flag possible on S.O question is:

> **primarily opinion-based**
>   Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

The main reason is we're looking for good answers for technical problems and not personal opinions, based on particular experience of the answerer.