# Reddit-like "contest mode" sorting option for meta threads

Tags: feature-request, sorting, per-site-meta

Reddit has [a feature wherein moderators can set threads to be sorted in "contest mode"](https://www.reddit.com/r/bestof2012/comments/159bww/introducing_contest_mode_a_tool_for_your_voting/). As the name suggests, it was originally designed for use with "contests", where the userbase is tasked with ordering a number of competing options by voting on them. To avoid biasing voters based on factors other than the content of the options, Reddit implements a few features that differ from typical sorts like "highest-voted" or "most recent":

- Scores are hidden. This prevents stuff like pile-on effects where voters vote for the things that already have the most votes.
- Options are sorted in a random order (that changes on each reload). This makes it so that e.g. early submissions don't get a huge advantage over late submissions.
- Other sort modes are unavailable. This prevents users from getting around these restrictions.

The ability to sort answers like this would be valuable on certain types of meta posts - in essence, any posts that function as polls. The question-collection threads that precede an election are an excellent example of this. Magic community-ads threads are another (and these especially suffer from early posts getting too many votes).

If this feature were to be implemented, it would make sense to add an option in the mod interface to allow diamond-users to turn contest mode on or off for a given meta post. And, of course, contest mode should only be available on meta.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would fit in to our systems, or work well given we *rely* on scores (etc) to sort things. I know this is specifically for Meta, but people use Metas for answers to site related questions, and votes are still really useful for ordering based on the better questions of the same topic. Advantages and disadvantages of early vs late submissions are not really the same here. Popularity and quality can dictate ordering here, but isn't that what this site is founded upon? Not sure "random order" would be useful, even with your specific criteria (or, it would be *rarely* useful)

Comment: @James I specifically said that this would be for posts that are polls, which means that you do not go there to _find_ a specific answer, but rather strictly to _vote_ on them.

Comment: I did not realise we had "polls".

Comment: @James Did you read the post? The question-collection threads that precede an election are polls!

Comment: So is your feature is solely for election threads? I would make that more clear then :) Or, explain what you feel are "polls" here :) (and yes, I read your post, a few times over to try to understand your request)

Comment: [Polls](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff) are generally considered [off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220732/suggestion-questions-with-polls). And, here's one specifically relating to [Metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233908/are-poll-style-questions-ever-acceptable-on-meta-sites).

Comment: Interesting idea...though I'm not sure I'd be happy with "*Other sort modes are unavailable*"

Comment: @James Surely you know what a poll is. A poll is any post whose function is to permit the userbase to select their most-preferred option(s) from a set of options. These posts do pop up on metas from time to time. Another example is community-ads threads. Some sites are particularly fond of polling for all sorts of things; [math.se] and MO come to mind.

Comment: @Catija Okay, do you want to make a post telling SE to stop running community-ads and question-collection threads, which are polls?

Comment: I'm not sure about how well this could work, so I'll refrain from judging, but I have to say I've always thought that later answers of the same quality of former answers usually get less upvotes (also due to the sorting, which I agree it's something difficult to solve as sorting answers by vote is how SE sites basically work); that's also the reason why we have a [FGITW problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/302251).

Comment: I don't personally see Community Ads posts as "polls"... I know that there are various formats for polling but most polls that I've run into limit the number of votes that can be cast by any particular person. And, even if you see them that way, they are *one* specific example that is created by SE managers, not by users or mods.

Comment: @senshin Did you read my comment? I suggested there are no polls on Stack Exchange and asked for clarification of how you would define polls here. Can you give some examples? Or at least explain what types of questions are polls (what your entire idea is for)? Otherwise, as I see it, your idea is pointless as there is no where for it to fit in.

Comment: @James I gave a definition, and provided as examples question-collection threads and community-ads threads in my previous comment. What is still unclear to you?

Comment: "*What is still unclear to you?*" Nothing now, I have re-read your post and re-read the bit which states "*The ability to sort answers like this would be valuable on certain types of meta posts - in essence, any posts that function as polls.*" Ok I get it - I look forward to sorting Stack Exchange Polls like Reddit. Sounds good.